# Can not pass varible to region in MKCoordinateRegion in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, dataflow, mkcoordinateregion

I need a variable map for each page. "number" chooses the element from the array of data that has been collected from JSON. The var "number" gives the error in "@State private var region".

The error is: Cannot use instance member 'number' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available.

Link of the project: https://github.com/parsadevuk/Swift-LondonParks/blob/main/LondonParks/Views%20Group/MapView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocationUI

struct MapView: View {

    var number : Int!
    init(number : Int!) {
        self.number = number ?? 0
    }

    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D( latitude: parksData[number].locationCoordinate.latitude, longitude: parksData[number].locationCoordinate.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.03, longitudeDelta: 0.03))

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
            .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .top)
        Image(parksData[number].imageName)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .bottom)
        }
    }

    private func setRegion(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2))
    }
}

struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView(number: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just some queries, 
why do you have `var number : Int!` with the `!`. What is it for? 
Where does `parksData` come from? How can you compile this code?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to use the number as the order of elements in the array.  parksData has details of parks including coordination (Latitude and Longitude). first park is parksData[0] and second park is parksData[1].

Comment: it works for images but soon as it goes into @State private var everything gets crazy and it gives this error: Cannot use instance member 'number' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available.   I do not get that error for Image(parksData[number].imageName) but I do get error in MKCoordinateRegion

Comment: You cannot instantiate `@State private var region = ...`
 using `number`, because it is not allowed **at that place in a View**.
 Use,
 `@State private var region = with latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0`, then add this to your `VStack{...}`:
 `.onAppear {
 region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D( latitude: parksData[number].locationCoordinate.latitude, longitude: parksData[number].locationCoordinate.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.03, longitudeDelta: 0.03))
}`

  Do the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/